# How to activate Windows during a massive OS deployment + machine testing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, clonezilla, disk-cloning, cloning

I need to install Windows on 200 Lenovo ThinkPad T460 and 200 Lenovo ThinkPad T470 laptops, which will then be delivered to various countries in Africa. These PCs are used and require a check of their functionality.

I've already prepared an image using Clonezilla and used it to deploy to 20 PCs at a time using a switch connected to a Clonezilla Lite Server instance. I captured the image in audit mode so that I can easily test the keyboard, audio, WiFi, and various peripherals. After all the tests are done, I update the UEFI BIOS version and run Sysprep with the following command:

```
%windir%\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown /unattend:unattend.xml
```

My unattended file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
    <settings pass="offlineServicing"></settings>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>0410:00000410</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassTPMCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassSecureBootCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassStorageCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>4</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassCPUCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>5</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassRAMCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>6</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /v BypassDiskCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <PersistAllDeviceInstalls>true</PersistAllDeviceInstalls>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <PersistAllDeviceInstalls>true</PersistAllDeviceInstalls>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OOBE" /v BypassNRO /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Path>net.exe accounts /maxpwage:UNLIMITED</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditSystem"></settings>
    <settings pass="auditUser"></settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <InputLocale>0410:00000410</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-GB</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-GB</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Name>***</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Password>
                            <Value>***</Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Username>***</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
                <Password>
                    <Value>***</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoLogonCount /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

I'm facing a doubt: since these PCs won't be connected to the internet, how can I keep them activated after the Sysprep generalize step?

I have already made some attempts, and after the reboot and login with the default admin user, Windows settings indicate that it is not activated.

Comment: If you're pre-creating an account anyway (and IIRC that's the only OOBE step worth paying attention to), is there actually a point in trying to deliver them '/generalize'd? Would it be okay to do the initial login and activation locally while you still have Internet access? (And to leave the account simply passwordless instead of messing with autologin/pwexpiry?)

Comment: I've put the BIOS install file and the unattend script on the desktop of Audit Administrator user.
Are you just suggesting to remove the generalize option inside the xml?
I was using this approach so that i don't have 200 laptopt with the same name.

Comment: Wiping keys/IDs is what generalize does. Normally you generalize when capturing the image, not after installation. You can add a key to the unattend file and it will activate during deployment for example

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't have all the product key to insert inside the unattended file :( it would be very time consuming to retrieve all and personalize the file. Even that way after the reboot the PCs won't probably have internet access so I don't know If the procedure is correct

Comment: Are you trying for offline activation? Windows 10/11 cannot be activated offline, the activation model is based on digital entitlement requiring contact with the Microsoft Activation Servers (or by phone).

Comment: Yes of course, as I said before I am activating the PC online while on audit mode. But then after sysprep the activation status is "unable to contact Windows licensing servers"